# Mongo DB atlas not returning any data When called from redash

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas, redash, mongoatlas

I have used Redash and am able to connect to the mongo db atlas. When I execute any query, I get 0 rows returned. I have confirmed that data is present in those collections.

I have used the below link to install redash
https://github.com/getredash/redash/wiki/Local-development-setup

Any suggestions to resolve this isuue would be really helpful

[image]